# ext4-fs error on Linux RAID1 configuration

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid-1, centos-7

I'm trying to configure a Dell PowerEdge R430 server with two RAID1 configurations.  One is intended to be for the OS and some archival storage, and the other is intended to be a seat for hypervisors. Two of the drives were relatively new (~2 years) HDDs and poached from other systems that are being disposed of. The two factory installed drives are SDDs. The SDDs are a single ext4 partition, but the HDDs are using LVM. I used the second RAID configuration of SATA HDDs as the system partition.  It's CentOS 7 with ext4 partitions, a proper boot partition, etc.. (I avoided xfs because I am not very used to it.)

Kind of out of the blue (I may have hit a power button prematurely when I was shutting down) I started getting thrown to emergency mode on boot.

The only other thing I'm noticing that's kind of out of the ordinary is that "Background initialization 0%" status in  in the PERC controller. It has been there for hours.

I ran `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/mapper/cl-root` - that found a ton of problems.

Unfortunately most of the other diagnostic information I can pass along is from screen shots.  I can only access this through an iDrac in its current state.

`/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt` claims /sysroot (/dev/mapper/cl-root) is not an OS tree.

Is there any hope I can boot my OS again?

[image: Initial errors when going into emergency mode]
[image: second raid disk configuration]
[image: rdsosreport]

Comment: At this point I'd probably suggest trying each disk individually (with RAID deactivated); Linux dmraid should be able to import PERC RAID disks – iirc they use the `lsi` format.

Comment: Try to boot from each disk? Or just try to read it?  Any advice or URLs about how to go about it? I am not very familiar with Linux RAID utilities. Should this be done on a separate machine?

Comment: How did you solve thi s?

Comment: Jeeze, I don't even remember anymore.  I think it turned out to be a very obscure bug in the firmware.  If a USB drive was plugged into a certain port (I want to say the leftmost on the front) it would crap out. But I might be mixing up issues, because that server had a host of problems.